# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" hitting when loading a xaml page for the second time and more attempts

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, augmented-reality

I am building stage wise in my augmented reality app. And I previously used a page named `SearchLocation.xaml` number of times to do a google geocoding search to find lat long of places.

But after I added more functionality to my app like the main AR page I am suspiciously hitting an exception while trying to search for a place's lat long through the `SearchLocation.xaml` page. It hits right after the `InitializeComponent()` method. To try and see what is causing this, I added a `Loaded += SearchLocation_Loaded event` and in the `SearchLocation_Loaded` event, I am setting the ContentPanel's visibility to visible(I hard coded its visibility to collapsed in xaml).

To my surprise, the exception hits everytime the ContentPanel shows up on screen. If I close the app completely and reopen it, it doesnt hit the first time, but when I try for the second time to open `SearchLocation.xaml`(which I linked to a tap event on a button in other page), I hit the exception. And the app closes.

I am completely clueless on what is causing this. Can anyone guide me in the right way so as to get rid of this exception ??

Code snippets will be provided if needed.

```
public SearchLocation()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += SearchLocation_Loaded;
}

void SearchLocation_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

The exception is throwing here because it is unhandled.

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.Message);
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

It happens whenever I open SearchLocation.xaml page through tapping a button from AddLocation.xaml for the second or third or any more further attempts.

I also used breakpoints to see at what line of code is the exception throwing, it is throwing right after everyline in public SearchLocation() {} has executed.

**UPDATE: I managed to understand what is causing this exception. Below are two screenshots, one which is taken when the page opens for the first time. The other is when the page opens again. I saw two properties were set to null. Both of these are storyboard animations. How do I set back from null to their storyboard animations again ?**

BEFORE:
[image: BEFORE]

AFTER:
[image: AFTER]

As you can see, there is no change when the page loads for the first time and the second time. I am now totally clueless what to do.

This is the content in my InitializeComponent().

```
public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/FindIt;component/SearchLocation.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
        this.HideTextBlock = ((System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard)(this.FindName("HideTextBlock")));
        this.UnhideTextBlock = ((System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard)(this.FindName("UnhideTextBlock")));
        this.LayoutRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("LayoutRoot")));
        this.ContentPanel = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("ContentPanel")));
        this.HelpText = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock)(this.FindName("HelpText")));
        this.SearchText = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(this.FindName("SearchText")));
        this.Search = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(this.FindName("Search")));
        this.Add = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(this.FindName("Add")));
        this.LocationMap = ((Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.Map)(this.FindName("LocationMap")));
    }
```

StoryBoard:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="HideTextBlock">
        <DoubleAnimation 
            Duration="0:0:0.4"
            From="120"
            To="0"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            Storyboard.TargetName="HelpText"
            d:IsOptimized="True" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="UnhideTextBlock">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Duration="0:0:0.4" 
            From="0"
            To="120"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
            Storyboard.TargetName="HelpText"
            d:IsOptimized="True" />
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

The method where storyboards are started:

```
private async void Search_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        HideTextBlock.Begin();
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();

        SetProgressIndicator(true);
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Searching";

        string searchText = SearchText.Text;
        HideTextBlock.Stop();
        //Enforce string checking algorithms

        searchText = searchText.Replace(" ", "+");
        //http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"+
            "?address={0}"+
            "&sensor=false";
        string baseUrl = string.Format(url, searchText);

        string googleResult = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Done";
        SetProgressIndicator(false);

        GoogleData apiData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleData>(googleResult);

        if (apiData.status == "OK")
        {
            HelpText.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            foreach (Result data in apiData.results)
            {
                latitude = data.geometry.location.lat;
                longitude = data.geometry.location.lng;

                foreach (AddressComponent addressData in data.address_components)
                {
                    locationName = addressData.long_name;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var mapCenter = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
            MapLayer myLayer = new MapLayer();
            Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();

            pin.Content = locationName;

            //pin.GeoCoordinate = mapCenter;
            pin.GeoCoordinate = mapCenter;

            MapOverlay myOverlay = new MapOverlay();
            myOverlay.Content = pin;
            myOverlay.GeoCoordinate = mapCenter;
            myOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0, 1);
            myLayer.Add(myOverlay);

            LocationMap.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            LocationMap.Layers.Add(myLayer);
            LocationMap.Center = mapCenter;
            LocationMap.ZoomLevel = 10;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a place name to search");
        UnhideTextBlock.Begin();
        UnhideTextBlock.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Share the code that you tried, and where is the object reference not set to an instance of an object throwing

Comment: I added the code. The exception is throwing right after the contentpanel is visible on screen. And sometimes after a few seconds.

Comment: Where exactly does the exception happen? The debugger should highlight the path.

Comment: Please provide where is it throwing

Comment: I updated the question and added where the exception is throwing.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Can you help now as I updated the question ?

Comment: @VenkatapathiRajuM Where's the storyboard is being set? In XAML or code-behind?

Comment: It is being set in xaml. As a page level resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I did considerable amount of research and I found what is giving me this exception. There is an async task which is GetGeopositionAsync in the page from which I am navigating to SearchLocation.xaml.

If I wait in AddLocation.xaml page until the geoposition is acquired, it doesnt throw me any exception when I navigate to SearchLocation.xaml page.

So I need to issue a cancellation token whenever I navigate away from the page. And IT WORKS !